# Timesensitive: Calculation of Yesterday is off

Tags: support, date-format

[How is SecureString "encrypted" and still usable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6982236/how-is-securestring-encrypted-and-still-usable/6982251#6982251)

I answered this question on Monday and the UTC time and my local time were both Monday. Today is UTC/Local Wednesday.

It might be off.

Comment: I think it's by design: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11/how-do-i-calculate-relative-time/12#12 (see comments) - that's a very, very, very old question and that comment pointing out the same thing as your question has been there nearly as long...

Comment: The text shows "2 days ago" and the tooltip is showing 12:39 on the 8/8 for me.

Comment: @ChrisF it would have **just** flipped from "yesterday", it's 12:49 UTC as at time of this comment

Comment: @Jon - ah yes indeed it would.

Comment: So, yesterday is anything less than 48 hours ago? (I have a similar case now, let's wait some more minutes).

Comment: Yes, just the 48 hour mark is the limit between "yesterday" and "two days ago". :-/

Comment: I think what causes the confusion is that yesterday is a period in time, where-as everything else is hours/minutes ago and the calculation uses time differences rather than checking whether the time is within the time-frame that we think of as 'yesterday'. It gets complicated though as things could get confusing for people not in UTC as obviously their 'yesterday' is a different period in time. I'd be tempted to remove it and go straight from hours to days