# Asked Date Miscalculated?

Tags: bug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Timesensitive: Calculation of Yesterday is off](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101694/timesensitive-calculation-of-yesterday-is-off)

Maybe it is just me, but this seems like a bug.

I looked at one of my posts, and it says **Asked Yesterday** and the date (when hovered) says:
`2013-01-08` but today's date is `2013-01-10`. In my opinion, that is a 2 day span, so shouldn't it say **2 days ago** or something similar?

Using php, this is how I would calculate it:

```
<?php
function date_posted($datePosted){
    $posted  = strtotime($datePosted);
    $now     = time();
    $seconds = ($now - $posted);
    $minutes = floor($seconds / 60);
    $days    = floor($minutes / 60);
    $years   = floor($days / 365);

    if($seconds <= 60){
        return "About a minute ago";
    }
    if($minutes < 60){
        return $minutes . " minute ago";
    }
    if($days <= 0){
        return "Today";
    }
    if($days <= 1){
        return "Yesterday";
    }
    if($days < 365){
        return $days . " days ago";
    }
    return $years . " years ago";
}

echo date_posted('2013-01-10 09:15:00');
echo "\n";
```

Comment: Is it less than 48 hours though..? The times are relative.

Comment: A link would be better :-)

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/20281/php-template-engine

Comment: Wait a bit more than an hour and all will be fine.

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: The question was asked 1 day and 23 hours ago (roughly). The time is UTC time. It will change in about an hour to 2 days.

Comment: That seems like an odd way to calculate it IMO. Most sites calculate things like that based on the date and not the time.

Comment: Nothing wrong with being unique.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12/13531

Comment: I agree that it is odd given the time is now 10/01/2013 16:17 I'd expect yesterday to mean anything from 09/01/2012 00:00 to 09/01/2012 23:59. After that I'd revert to hours. Guess SE people have their reasons though.

Comment: @mmyers my calculation is easier :)

Comment: @RyanNaddy: Doesn't that have the same problem? i.e. you're basing yesterday on the number of seconds since the current time, not midnight. I think you've got the same problem with today. i.e. Post at 17:00; treated as today until after 16:59 next day, UTC. I don't think a 'yesterday' or 'today' can work.

Comment: Fixed, I ran it through php and it works.